# Git for Web Developing

Tags: git, bash

I'm attempting to create a set of git repositories and web folders in a server using the post-update hook. It would be something like:

//server/dev (for dev files) and //server/web (the apache main path)

The post-update hook for the //server/dev git repositories:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset GIT_DIR
PROJECT=`basename $(pwd)`
cd ../../web/${PROJECT}

echo "Updating `pwd`..."
git reset --hard
```

I see the update message while pushing stuff, but the //server/web folder just won't update. It keeps showing the first commit HEAD.

"HEAD is now at XXXXXXX First Commit"

There's some solutions around, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Comment: Have you looked at a few of all the times this problem has been handled on this very website?

Comment: you are using git reset instead of git pull to get the content and merge it in the current branch.

Comment: ndim, it would be just amazing if you could point one of them that can help me out on this.

Comment: Scharron, I want the web repository to be always the last commmit. Pull will not guarantee that this repository will be always free of conflicts. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

If the repository is at some point at the last commit, then updates are made, and you pull, the pull should always be a fast-forward, which by definition cannot cause merge conflicts. The only case in which it's not is when you push a non-fast-forward update into your central repository, which you generally should not do.

Of course, you might as well plan for the worst, and make absolutely sure that this will work, even with non-fast-forward updates, so you could do:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
```